# My css import fails

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, jsp

stupid HTML question but I ve spent a lot of time trying to solve it.

I have difficulties to include some css files into a jsp page.

When I try:

```
<link href="<c:url value="/css/bootstrap.css"/>" rel="stylesheet">
```

And when I try:

```
<link href="<c:url value="/css/bootstrap.css"/>" rel="stylesheet">
```

server returns a 404 error and fails to import the file:

```
 {code="404", msg="/css/bootstrap.css", uri=/css/bootstrap.css}
```

The text

```
" rel="stylesheet">
```

gets displayed on the web page.

The imports where at the top of the  to avoid issues with previous lines.

The file is IS in /css dir 
and I copied it in all possible places where it could be seeked to make sure.
So I m really puzzled...
Is there something obvious top that knocks somebody's bells?

Comment: What language is `<c:url value="/css/bootstrap.css"/>`? Update the tags on your question.

Comment: @j08691 Looks like JavaServer Pages. OP, please update your question with relevant information.

Comment: I have another method in mind, but are you really trying to use `<c:url>`?

Comment: Yep it concerns a jsp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had forgotten to include this:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
```

To make it work:

```
<link href="<c:url value="/css/bootstrap.css"/>" rel="stylesheet">
```

Answer (score -1):

Maybe the use of single quotes inside double quotes will fix it.

`<link href="<c:url value='/css/bootstrap.css'/>" rel="stylesheet">`

Also, have you tried simply

`<link href="../css/loginstyle.css" rel="stylesheet">`
?

Comment: Did you mean *quotes*?